# Why is my image showing in preview but not in the app simulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-imageview

I'm struggling with an issue with the ImageView tag. It seems to load a PNG from the drawable folder in preview, but when I run the app on my phone via the simulator the image does not show up.

Here's the XML layout for my image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    tools:context="org.tensorflow.demo.CameraActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start/Stop" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clearButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="110px"
        android:text="Clear" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="240px"
        android:src="@drawable/record_circle" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Here's the code in my activity to load the image as well:

```
ImageView circleView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cView);
circleView.setImageResource(0);

Drawable circleDraw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.record_circle);
circleDraw = (circleDraw);
circleView.setImageDrawable(circleDraw);
```

Thanks!

**I've tried using both src and background in the android:src="@drawable..." property

Comment: remove background and try this  android:src="@drawable/record_circle"
also don't need to load via code

Comment: Thanks! I actually tried this a little bit earlier, and it didn't seem to work either. Could the code be messing things up?

Comment: have you tried after removing the code?

Comment: `circleDraw = (circleDraw);` - what is this line supposed to do?

Comment: Give your full layout code

Comment: in which folder under the /res directory you kept the image?

Comment: circleDraw = (circleDraw); what does this mean ? and also if you have specified the image in the xml then why are you again setting it in code ?

Comment: Commented out the code - that didn't seem to fix it. So the issue doesn't seem to be there.

Comment: The image is in the drawable folder under the res directory

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/cView"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="46dp"
android:layout_marginTop="240px"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/record_circle" />
```

Here is an example of the app namespace import:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
```

Note that this is the top-most layout, so it may be "LinearLayout," Or whatever you are using

Comment: This gave me a resource linking failed error. I'm pretty sure the file path is correct though.

Comment: You may need to include the app namespace in the top element of your xml. Updated my answer to show what I mean

Comment: Thanks - I tried this but it resulted in the same error. It says that the namespace declaration is never used as well

Comment: Not a problem. Sorry that didnt help. Can you update your answer with the full XML?